# q1,median,q3 WEKA java

Tags: java, weka

Currently I am developing a java gui using WEKA. However, I am facing problem in finding out the q1,median,q3. Just want to compute the values, no plot graph is needed. Is there anyway to compute this? truly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

The source code or weka-src.jar is shipped with WEKA distribution. 
Look for the class InterquartileRange.java.

i.e.
weka-src/src/main/java/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/InterquartileRange.java

Feel free to modify per your requirements.

Ref: [WEKA API Javadoc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/) weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.InterquartileRange